# Generating a recovery phrase for a RSA key-pair

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, keys, key-recovery

What is an optimal way to associate a RSA key-pair with a recovery phrase/seed for access recovery purposes? I've seen a lot of cryptocurrency wallets provide this feature, however, I'm not looking to create a blockchain or anything. Just a wallet/key-pair with a recovery seed.